# How to calculate individual means,SDs,relative proportions from two gaussian mixtures?

Tags: python, r, distribution, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a csv data sampled from 2 gaussian mixtures. How can I calculate individual means,SDs & relative proportions from it? Is there specific formula or function in Pyhton/R for them? Any suggestion will help. Thanks in advance.

When I plot it, looks like this.

[image]

Comment: The result of the Gaussian mixture model should give you these parameters.

Comment: Gaussian Mixture Model from scikit-learn is first thing to try: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html